# Is there a general way to remove substring which starts with a non-spaced capital letter in R?

Tags: r, string, gsub

While this is hard describe in writing. I'm trying to find a *general* way to make this:

```r
 [1] "Nature's Corner, Inc.Grocery StoresHerbsBBB Rating: A+"        
 [2] "Peapod Pick-UpGrocery StoresFood Delivery Service"             
 [3] "Stop & ShopGrocery Stores"                                     
 [4] "WegmansGrocery Stores"
```

Into this:

```r
 [1] "Nature's Corner, Inc."        
 [2] "Peapod Pick-Up"             
 [3] "Stop & Shop"                                     
 [4] "Wegmans"
```

Is there a way to write this with regular expressions using `gsub`?

Comment: Is it always 'Grocery Stores...' that you are trying to remove?

Comment: @Wil I'm looking for a general solution. Not just grocery stores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do (where `s` is your array of strings):

```
gsub(pattern = "([a-z.])[A-Z].*", replacement = "\\1", x = s)
```

What this does is: look for a lowercase letter or . followed by an uppercase letter.  Keep the first character and then remove everything that follows.

Result:

```
[1] "Nature's Corner, Inc." "Peapod Pick-Up"        "Stop & Shop"           "Wegmans"
```

(with a narrower console)

```
[1] "Nature's Corner, Inc."
[2] "Peapod Pick-Up"       
[3] "Stop & Shop"          
[4] "Wegmans"
```

Alternative:

If the part that you want to remove always starts with 'Grocery' do

```
gsub(pattern = "Grocery.*", replacement = "", x = s)
```

But this may convert *"Mom & Pop's GroceryGrocery Stores"* to *"Mom & Pop's"*